# How to search for overlapping time slices?

Tags: c#

I have a list of objects, there are multiple objects in list and every object contain `StartTime` and `EndTime`, for example:

```
StartTime: 09:00 EndTime: 10:00
StartTime: 09:30 EndTime: 10:15
StartTime: 10:00 EndTime: 10:30
StartTime: 11:00 EndTime: 11:30
StartTime: 11:45 EndTime: 13:00
StartTime: 12:45 EndTime: 14:00
```

In the above example there are three groups of time intervals with and without overlapping:

```
1) StartTime: 09:00 EndTime: 10:30
2) StartTime: 11:00 EndTime: 11:30
3) StartTime: 11:45 EndTime: 14:00
```

Please suggest how can I modify my query to get the results like above example, any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: The general answer is "show us your code".  But that's *ESPECIALLY* important here, because you're giving us no idea exactly how you're "querying".  Please update your post with some example code.

Comment: i'm using simple list query as

var lstTimeSpans = db.TableName.ToList();

Comment: You haven't given any indication of what you are trying to query. A `list of objects as a Group` doesn't explain this.

Comment: currently i'm getting all objects in my list, but i want only group of objects that are overlaping for example in the above example StartTime: 09:00 and EndTime: 10:30 is a group that describes user is busy between 09:00 to 10:30 because there are also other requests that lie in this time interval so, i pick only start and end, i don't know how to do it

Comment: related : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11480031/merging-overlapping-time-intervals

Comment: related : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13130204/combine-time-ranges?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: I will also recommend : https://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/Range.html and implement intersection .

Answer (score 1):

For a group this will print other groups that overlaps it:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    public struct Group
    {
        public Group(TimeSpan startTime, TimeSpan endTime)
        {
            StartTime = startTime;
            EndTime = endTime;
        }

        public TimeSpan StartTime { get; }

        public TimeSpan EndTime { get; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"{nameof(StartTime)}: {StartTime}, {nameof(EndTime)}: {EndTime}";
        }

        public bool Equals(Group other)
        {
            return StartTime.Equals(other.StartTime) && EndTime.Equals(other.EndTime);
        }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            return obj is Group other && Equals(other);
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            unchecked
            {
                return (StartTime.GetHashCode() * 397) ^ EndTime.GetHashCode();
            }
        }

        public static bool operator ==(Group left, Group right)
        {
            return left.Equals(right);
        }

        public static bool operator !=(Group left, Group right)
        {
            return !left.Equals(right);
        }
    }

    internal static class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var groups = new[]
            {
                new Group(new TimeSpan(9, 0, 0), new TimeSpan(10, 0, 0)),
                new Group(new TimeSpan(9, 30, 0), new TimeSpan(10, 15, 0)),
                new Group(new TimeSpan(10, 0, 0), new TimeSpan(10, 30, 0)),
                new Group(new TimeSpan(11, 0, 0), new TimeSpan(11, 30, 0)),
                new Group(new TimeSpan(11, 45, 0), new TimeSpan(13, 0, 0)),
                new Group(new TimeSpan(12, 45, 0), new TimeSpan(14, 0, 0))
            };

            foreach (var group in groups)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("-------------------");
                Console.WriteLine(group);

                var array = GetOverlapping(group, groups).ToArray();

                foreach (var item in array)
                    Console.WriteLine(item);
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public static IEnumerable<Group> GetOverlapping(Group group, IEnumerable<Group> groups)
        {
            var except = groups.Except(new[] {group});

            foreach (var item in except)
                if (item.StartTime >= group.StartTime && item.StartTime < group.EndTime)
                    yield return item;
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

```
-------------------
StartTime: 09:00:00, EndTime: 10:00:00
StartTime: 09:30:00, EndTime: 10:15:00
-------------------
StartTime: 09:30:00, EndTime: 10:15:00
StartTime: 10:00:00, EndTime: 10:30:00
-------------------
StartTime: 10:00:00, EndTime: 10:30:00
-------------------
StartTime: 11:00:00, EndTime: 11:30:00
-------------------
StartTime: 11:45:00, EndTime: 13:00:00
StartTime: 12:45:00, EndTime: 14:00:00
-------------------
StartTime: 12:45:00, EndTime: 14:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as the objects are ordered by `StartTime` then this should work just fine:

```
var objects = new[]
{
    new { StartTime = new TimeSpan(9, 0, 0), EndTime = new TimeSpan(10, 0, 0) },
    new { StartTime = new TimeSpan(9, 30, 0), EndTime = new TimeSpan(10, 15, 0) },
    new { StartTime = new TimeSpan(10, 0, 0), EndTime = new TimeSpan(10, 30, 0) },
    new { StartTime = new TimeSpan(11, 0, 0), EndTime = new TimeSpan(11, 30, 0) },
    new { StartTime = new TimeSpan(11, 45, 0), EndTime = new TimeSpan(13, 0, 0) },
    new { StartTime = new TimeSpan(12, 45, 0), EndTime = new TimeSpan(14, 0, 0) },
};

var results = // List<{ StartTime = ..., EndTime = ... }>
    objects
        .Skip(1)
        .Aggregate(
            objects.Take(1).ToList(),
            (a, x) =>
            {
                if (a.Last().EndTime > x.StartTime)
                {
                    a[a.Count - 1] = new
                    {
                        a.Last().StartTime,
                        EndTime =
                            a.Last().EndTime > x.EndTime
                            ? a.Last().EndTime
                            : x.EndTime
                    };
                }
                else
                {
                    a.Add(x);
                }
                return a;
            });
```

That gives:

```
StartTime EndTime 
------------------
09:00:00 10:30:00 
11:00:00 11:30:00 
11:45:00 14:00:00
```

Comment: Thanks @Enigmativity, can you please make this logic a bit simple?

Comment: @DotNetDeveloper - Sorry, are you asking me to explain the code?

Comment: @DotNet Developer - instead of just saying "thanks" ... why don't you "upvote" and "accept" the reply?  And upvote the other replies you found helpful?

Answer (score 0):

I would use Aggregate but a little another way than @Enigmativity:

```
var intervals = new [] {
    new { StartTime = TimeSpan.Parse("09:00"), EndTime = TimeSpan.Parse("10:00") },
    new { StartTime = TimeSpan.Parse("09:30"), EndTime = TimeSpan.Parse("10:15") },
    new { StartTime = TimeSpan.Parse("10:00"), EndTime = TimeSpan.Parse("10:30") },
    new { StartTime = TimeSpan.Parse("11:00"), EndTime = TimeSpan.Parse("11:30") },
    new { StartTime = TimeSpan.Parse("11:45"), EndTime = TimeSpan.Parse("13:00") },
    new { StartTime = TimeSpan.Parse("12:45"), EndTime = TimeSpan.Parse("14:00") }};

var result = intervals.Aggregate(
    new List<(TimeSpan from, TimeSpan to)>(),
    (accumulator, interval) => {
        var index = accumulator.FindIndex(v => 
            v.from <= interval.EndTime 
            && v.to >= interval.StartTime);

        if (index != -1) {
            accumulator[index] = (
                from: accumulator[index].from < interval.StartTime ? accumulator[index].from : interval.StartTime,
                to: accumulator[index].to > interval.EndTime ? accumulator[index].to : interval.EndTime
            );                        
        }
        else {
            accumulator.Add((from: interval.StartTime, to: interval.EndTime));
        }

        return accumulator;
    }
); 

/*
({09:00:00}, {10:30:00})
({11:00:00}, {11:30:00})
({11:45:00}, {14:00:00})
*/
```