# Merging and converting string intervals using Linq

Tags: c#, string, linq

I have intervals ranging from `"0"` to `"1000000000000000"` (10<sup>15</sup>) represented in `string` objects of the form `"123-456789012345"`, i.e. `"{start}-{end}"`.

I would like to merge intervals that overlap or are inclusive in other intervals and convert to type `long` using linq.

So far I have only ordered the intervals using the code below where `r` (for example) is

```
string[] r = new[]
{
    "123-456",
    "400-191"
};

var range = r.OrderBy(entry => long.Parse(entry.Split('-')[0]))
    .ThenBy(entry => long.Parse(entry.Split('-')[1]))
    .ToArray();
```

Could someone share a Linq function I would use to merge and convert the intervals?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11480031/merging-overlapping-time-intervals) might be some help, it's just dealing with `DateTime`s rather than `int`s.

Answer (score 0):

[Here's one approach](http://share.linqpad.net/l6eqv6.linq):

```
void Main()
{
    var rangesInput = new[]
    {
        "123-456",
        "400-191",
    };

    var ranges = (from x in rangesInput
                  let s = x.Split('-')
                  select new Range(long.Parse(s[0]), long.Parse(s[1])))
                .Aggregate(new List<Range>(), (agg, range) =>
                {
                    var intersecting = agg.FirstOrDefault(r => range.Intersects(r));

                    if (intersecting != null)
                    {
                        intersecting.UnionWith(range);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        agg.Add(range);
                    }

                    return agg;
                });
    ranges.Dump();
}

class Range
{
    public Range(long end1, long end2)
    {
        Start = Math.Min(end1, end2);
        End = Math.Max(end1, end2);
    }

    public long Start { get; private set; }
    public long End { get; private set; }

    public bool Intersects(Range range) => Math.Max(range.Start, Start) <= Math.Min(range.End, End);

    public void UnionWith(Range range)
    {
        Start = Math.Min(Start, range.Start);
        End = Math.Max(End, range.End);
    }
}
```

Note this would get pretty slow if there are a lot of ranges to merge. In case of a large amount of data, you'd want a different data structure: [an interval tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree).