# merge multiple generic list reocrds into one on condition C#

Tags: c#, mergesort, tobjectlist

I had a task where i've to add new record after comparing previous one

Ex.
there are Layers 1,2,3,... in this

layer 1 have records like this

[image]

Now I can add records of layer 2 only if it start and end is within Layer 1s start end

I created a simple < && > logic it worked. But then new case arrives that if layer 1 contains sequential records then it should be treated as one record first like this

[image]

As records are not necessarily needed to add in a sequence of Start-End then the first end is seconds Start, I'm unable to use Min Max.

Please any suggestion to merge those list records...

```
foreach (var item in prevCompleteAct)
{
   if ((_start >= item.Start&& _start <= item.End)&& (_end >= item.Start&& _end <= item.End))
   {
        res = "ok";
        break;
   }                                    
}
```

This is not actual records, the tables shown are just a simplified portion for understanding

**A general line example how records get inserts before are**

1. there is a line consider is of 100m, where the user split it into
   10m brackets,
2. Now a user has to apply layers of different colors on it which is in
   layer sequence. a user add layer 1 from 00 to 10 then 10 to 20 and
   skip 20 to 30 as there was a difficulty and continue with 30 to 50
   and so on, so it's not like user has to paint layer 1 sequentially
   but it is mandatory to done all line means 00 to 100m for layer 1.
3. Now the additional condition is when he starts to apply layer 2 for
   eg. 00 to 20 then it's mandatory that layer 1's 00 to20 must be done
   before

**Update**

thank you @DragandDrop, https://dotnetfiddle.net/4Q6Pyb given by you is helpful!

Comment: What if the end is in the range of the second but greater that the start? For now your example only have End == Start but what happends for {100, 300} {200, 400} does it get merge into {100 , 400}

Comment: you give lots of detail which is gd, but its really hard to follow what you are wanting... maybe better to show... before.... then "after incorrect" and "after correct"...

Comment: no, start and end never overlap

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11480031/merging-overlapping-time-intervals

Comment: @seabizkit I just wanted to that table merge as I showed in pic, as rest part will be manageable if I get that new merged list

Comment: so find all there one where there a cap, and merge one which are lower than the gap into the gap... its still a bit confusing to me. are the sections ranges denoted by the gap aka there is no 400 so the max before this... everything should be ranged into?

Comment: the general line is there is a line consider is of 100m, where user split it into 10m brackets, Now user have to apply layers of different color on it which is in layer sequence. You add layer 1 from 00 to 10 then 10 to 20 and skip 20 to 30 as there was difficulty. and continue with 30 to 50 and so on

Comment: @Seabizkit so its not like we have to paint sequentially but it is mandatory to done all line means 00 to 100m

Comment: @T.Giri im clearly not the only one not following...... i am trying... like i said best... update question with "before".... then "after incorrect" and "after correct"

Comment: This answer on the related question provide a simple algo. I'm pretty sure if will be fit. give, an ordered list of layers on start date. has there is no over laping you don't need the max and the algo is even simplier.

Comment: @DragandDrop yes, thank you for the link, I'm trying to implement it my code now

Comment: Sorry I failed to link the answers. https://stackoverflow.com/a/11480442/6560478. The implementation is pretty easy => https://dotnetfiddle.net/4Q6Pyb.

Comment: thank you @DragandDrop, I manage to get it done without sorting it, yet my code it a little bit more time-consuming. will definitely gonna implement it later one